# Stop users from registering spaces in their usernames

Tags: php, mysql, html, trim

I've encounted an error, my registeration form allows users to register usernames with spaces ie, "user name" when it should be just "username" with no spaces.

I've tried searching and reading many tutorials, but most don't help me at all.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to a working tutorial, or tell me what I've done wrong.

I tried using strip the spaces, a tut but I'm not 100% how to do it.

But here is what I've done...

Register page

```
<?
session_start();
include("config.php");
include("clean.php");
$act = clean($_GET[act]); 
$sqlcontent = mysql_query("select * from usr_config");
$content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlcontent);
$rand = rand(0,999);
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Usersystem Register Page &bull; <? echo("$content[site]");?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <tr>
      <? if($content[regen]==1) { 
      if($act!=register)
      { ?>
      <form action="register_new.php?act=register" method="post">
        <div align="center">Username:<br />
            <input type="text" name="username" class="login" maxlength="20" />
          <br />
          <br />
          Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <br />
          <br />
          Email Address:<br />
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <br />
          <br />
    Country:<br />
        <SELECT name="countrywhere">
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="&#197;land&nbsp;Islands">&#197;land Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American&nbsp;Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua&nbsp;and&nbsp;Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Bosnia&nbsp;and&nbsp;Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option value="Bouvet&nbsp;Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="British&nbsp;Indian&nbsp;Ocean&nbsp;Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="Brunei&nbsp;Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="Burkina&nbsp;Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Cape&nbsp;Verde">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="Cayman&nbsp;Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="Central&nbsp;African&nbsp;Republic">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Christmas&nbsp;Island">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="Cocos&nbsp;(Keeling)&nbsp;Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
    <option value="Congo,&nbsp;The&nbsp;Democratic&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of&nbsp;the">Congo, The Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="Cook&nbsp;Islands">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="Costa&nbsp;Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="C&#244;te&nbsp;d'Ivoire">C&#244;te d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="Czech&nbsp;Republic">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
    <option value="Dominican&nbsp;Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
    <option value="El&nbsp;Salvador">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="Equatorial&nbsp;Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="Falkland&nbsp;Islands&nbsp;(Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="Faroe&nbsp;Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="French&nbsp;Guiana">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="French&nbsp;Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="French&nbsp;Southern&nbsp;Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
    <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
    <option value="Heard&nbsp;Island&nbsp;and&nbsp;McDonald&nbsp;Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="Holy&nbsp;See&nbsp;(Vatican&nbsp;City&nbsp;State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
    <option value="Hong&nbsp;Kong">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="Iran,&nbsp;Islamic&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="Korea,&nbsp;Democratic&nbsp;People's&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="Korea,&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="Lao&nbsp;People's&nbsp;Democratic&nbsp;Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
    <option value="Libyan&nbsp;Arab&nbsp;Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
    <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="Marshall&nbsp;Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Micronesia,&nbsp;Federated&nbsp;States&nbsp;of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="Moldova,&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="Netherlands&nbsp;Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option value="New&nbsp;Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="New&nbsp;Zealand">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
    <option value="Norfolk&nbsp;Island">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="Northern&nbsp;Mariana&nbsp;Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
    <option value="Palestinian&nbsp;Territory,&nbsp;Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
    <option value="Papua&nbsp;New&nbsp;Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option value="Puerto&nbsp;Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
    <option value="R&#233;union">R&#233;union</option>
    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="Russian&nbsp;Federation">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="Saint&nbsp;Helena">Saint Helena</option>
    <option value="Saint&nbsp;Kitts&nbsp;and&nbsp;Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="Saint&nbsp;Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="Saint&nbsp;Pierre&nbsp;and&nbsp;Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="Saint&nbsp;Vincent&nbsp;and&nbsp;the&nbsp;Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
    <option value="San&nbsp;Marino">San Marino</option>
    <option value="Sao&nbsp;Tome&nbsp;and&nbsp;Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="Saudi&nbsp;Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
    <option value="Serbia&nbsp;and&nbsp;Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="Sierra&nbsp;Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="Solomon&nbsp;Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
    <option value="South&nbsp;Africa">South Africa</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Sri&nbsp;Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option value="Svalbard&nbsp;and&nbsp;Jan&nbsp;Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="Syrian&nbsp;Arab&nbsp;Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="Taiwan,&nbsp;Province&nbsp;of&nbsp;China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="Tanzania,&nbsp;United&nbsp;Republic&nbsp;of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
    <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
    <option value="Trinidad&nbsp;and&nbsp;Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="Turks&nbsp;and&nbsp;Caicos&nbsp;Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="United&nbsp;Arab&nbsp;Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="United&nbsp;Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="United&nbsp;States">United States</option>
    <option value="United&nbsp;States&nbsp;Minor&nbsp;Outlying&nbsp;Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="Viet&nbsp;Nam">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="Virgin&nbsp;Islands,&nbsp;British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="Virgin&nbsp;Islands,&nbsp;U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="Wallis&nbsp;and&nbsp;Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="Western&nbsp;Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </SELECT>
          <br />
          <br />
          Username Colour:<br />
          <select name="usercolour">
        <OPTION value="#000000">Black</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#FF0000">Red</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#00FF00">Green</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#0000FF">Blue</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#FFFF00">Yellow</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#FF00FF">Pink</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#C0C0C0">Grey</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#FF6600">Orange</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#990066">Purple</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#4682B4">Steelblue</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#DDA0DD">Plum</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#AFEEEE">Paleturquoise</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#D87093">Palevioletred</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#191970">Midnightblue</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#8A2BE2">Blue Violet</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#7FFF00">Chartreuse</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#DC143C">Crimson</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#008B8B">Dark Cyan</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#8B0000">Dark Red</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="#FF1493">Deep Pink</OPTION>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          Gender:<br />
         <SELECT name="sexmalefemale">
         <OPTION value="Boy">Boy</OPTION>
         <OPTION value="Girl">Girl</OPTION>
         </SELECT>
          <br />
          <br />
    About Yourself:<br />
        <textarea name="abouturself" cols=30 rows=5 wrap=physical></textarea>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input type="hidden" name="random" value="<? echo("$rand");?>" />
          Special word<br />
          <input type="text" name="word" />
          <input type="hidden" name="dateofjoin" value="<? print(Date("F d, Y")); ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="msg" value="Welcome" />
          <br />
          <br />
          Enter the number shown below<br />
          <strong><? echo("$rand");?></strong><br />
          <input type="text" name="rand" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastedited" value="Registered an account @ <?php 

/** 
 * Just add this in your page where you 
 * want the date/time to appear 
 * 
 * For more configuration options look 
 * in the PHP manual at http://uk2.php.net/date 
 */ 

// Displays in the format Saturday, November 22, 2003 11.38 
echo date("l, F d, Y h:i" ,time()); 

?> " />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>
      </form>
      <? 
      }
      if($act==register)
      {
          $username = clean($_POST[username]);
          $username = str_replace (" ", "", $username);
          $msg = clean($_POST[msg]);
          $subject = "Welcome";
          $sendto = $username;
          $sentfrom = "admin";
          $user = "$username";
          $reason = "joining the site";
          $badge = "member.png";
          $display = "1";
          $privmsg = $msg;
      $password2 = clean($_POST[password]);
      $password = md5($_POST[password]);
      $email = clean($_POST[email]);
      $countrywhere = clean($_POST[countrywhere]);
      $avator = clean($_POST[avator]);
      $sexmalefemale = clean($_POST[sexmalefemale]);
      $usercolour = clean($_POST[usercolour]);
      $abouturself = clean($_POST[abouturself]);
      $rand = clean($_POST[rand]);
      $lastedited = clean($_POST[lastedited]);
      $random = $_POST[random];
      $word = clean($_POST[word]);
      $dateofjoin = clean($_POST[dateofjoin]);
      $check = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$username'");
      $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
      if($check2==0)
      {
      if($username!="" && $password!="")
      {
      if($rand==$random)
      {
          $qry = mysql_query("insert into usr_pm(subject, sendto, sentfrom, privmsg) values('$subject', '$sendto', '$sentfrom', '$privmsg')");
          $result = @mysql_query($qry);
      $gry2 = mysql_query("insert into usr_users(username, password, word, dateofjoin, email, countrywhere, avator, sexmalefemale, usercolour, abouturself, lastedited) values('$username', '$password', '$word', '$dateofjoin', '$email', '$countrywhere', '$avator', '$sexmalefemale', '$usercolour', '$abouturself', '$lastedited')");
          $result = @mysql_query($qry2);
          $qry3 = mysql_query("insert into usr_badge(user, reason, badge, display) values('$user', '$reason', '$badge', '$display')");
          $result = @mysql_query($qry3);
      echo("You are now signed up to our site!");
      if($content[emailvert]==1)
      {
      $emailbody = "Thanks for registering at the $content[site] usersystem! \n \n We'd like to take this chance to confirm all of your details, just so you know how to log in and get the most out of your experience! \n \n --- \n username: $username \n Password: $password2 \n Your secret code: $sec \n Your secret word: $word \n \n -- \n \n Thanks, \n $content[site] Management --";
     $mail =  mail($email,"Welcome to the $content[site] usersystem!", $emailbody, "From: <$content[email]>");
     if(!$mail)
     echo("<br />Could not send the email at this time, please check you filled out the previous page completely and try again..");
     else echo("<br /></br></br><b>Please go to the email you provided to us and confirm your account, after 1 week we will suspend your account if you do not confirm.</b>");
      }
      }
      else echo("The number you entered did not match that displayed!");
      }
      else echo("You have not entered filled out all the required fields, you need to do so in order to continue..");
      }
      else
      echo("username is already in use!");
      }
      ?>
      <? }
      else echo("Register disabled"); ?>
```

clean.php (meant strip spaces)

```
<?php
function clean($str)
{
$cleaned = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(addslashes(stripslashes( $str ))));

return $cleaned;
}
?>
```

Functions

```
/*
Clean Variables
*/
function clean($str)
{
$cleaned = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(addslashes(stripslashes( $str ))));
return $cleaned;
}
/*
End Function
*/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Those functions won't strip spaces, only html tags

Comment: Hey user1482117 ... do us a big favor? Next time don't paste a ton of code... we don't need a complete list of every country in the world... edit it down to some minimal snippet of code that demonstrates your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelSpolsky missed out South Sudan too!

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
```

will remove all spaces.

Additionally, my PHP is a little rusty but doesn't `stripslashes` do the inverse of `addslashes`, therefore doing one then the other is doing nothing?

Comment: Glenn, It does not remove spaces in a username when registering.

Comment: I tried this now, $username = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST[username]) and got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/********/public_html/register_new.php on line 477"

Comment: You need quotes around username inside the `$_POST`, i.e. `$username = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST["username"])`

Comment: That error is because you have to do `$_POST['username']` instead of `$_POST[username]`. You have to use quotes or otherwise username is treated as a constant.

Comment: Chris, I get an error doing that too. On line 477! hm.. strange.

Comment: Do you have a semicolon after it?

Comment: You have to add quotes everywhere you do `$_POST['something']`. ie: `$_POST[email]`, `$_POST[msg]`

Comment: Glenn I forgot that, and now it's working perfectly. Been trying to find a fix all day. Not very bright.. Hope everyone who needed help regarding this topic now has it :)

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for is "form validation".

You don't want accept an input unless it confirms to your concept of what's valid.

You have two levels where you can check for validation: one the client side (through javascript) and on the server side.

On the client side you could use something like the jQuery form validation plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

On the server side you could use the substr_count() function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: AllInOne has a point, perhaps validation is more what you should be doing rather than modifying the user's input after they submit it

Answer (score 1):

Do a str_replace(' ', '', $string) This will take 'user name' and return username. Easiest would be doing it in php unless you don't want users to do it. Then use javascript with.

```
function checkform(){
  var username = $('form[name = username]').val()
  var re =  /\s/g;
  if(re.test(username)){
   alert("You can't have a space") 
   return false;
   }
  }
```

To explain:
first we get the username input value and put it in a variable. Then we test the username to see if it contains an spaces /s. If it does have a space then we alert them. the var re checks for a space in the string using the test method. Return False stops the form from submitting. You from would look like

```
<form onsubmit="checkfrom()">
```

Does that help explain it. I'm doing it from memory so might be off.

Answer (score 1):

For just spaces, use str_replace

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all white space, use preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) should work. :)

Comment: That will only remove it from the beginning and end, not in the middle.

Comment: That only removes spaces from the beginning & end of the string